# How to Put Some Text in every Post Content on WordPress Automatically?

Tags: wordpress, posts

I want that Every Post Must Include this in every Post Like Template. For Example:

My Post Title: Time Management
Post Content: [So Friends, How is our Article of "**Post-Title**". Do You Like it? Don't Forget to Comment below if Any Queries. For More Article regarding "**Post-Title**" Subscribe Us.]

I want this to put in every post at the end of the Article Automatically.
Please Help Me. If Anyone Knows it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_the_content_in_the_main_loop' );

function filter_the_content_in_the_main_loop( $content ) {

    // Check if we're inside the main loop in a single post page.
    if ( is_single() && in_the_loop() && is_main_query() ) {

       return esc_html__("So Friends, How is our Article of ".get_the_title().". Do You Like it? Don't Forget to Comment below if Any Queries. For More Article regarding ".get_the_title()." Subscribe Us.").$content;
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: you can also create your own template and assign same template to particular post

Comment: I am trying to make some text bold "<b>" and adding h2 "<h2>" code but the code not working.

Comment: use _e() instead esc_html()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205061/discussion-between-dhruv-and-himanshu-jain).